# Python Opencv error (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow' How can I solve this problem?

Tags: python, opencv, path, windows-11

```
import cv2 as cv

path = 'Photos\dog1.jpg'
img = cv.imread(path)

cv.imshow('Dog', img)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows
```

It gave an error like this ... error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

I am running this code on windows 11 and on visiual studio codes. It didn't show the image I tried everything. I searched about it but I couldn't find anything I tired every thing down below. When I didn't used whole path I placed the folder in the same directory. Also the problem is about reading the image there is something wrong with the path like entering a wrong path ect. but I am sure that I didn't enter the wrong path I think it is not about that. I searched it and try to find a solution to it for more then 8 hours:

1. path = 'Photos\dog1.jpg' Backwards Slash
2. path = 'Photos\\dog1.jpg' Double Backwards Slash
3. path = 'Photos/dog1.jpg' Normal Slash
4. path = r'Photos\dog1.jpg' Normal Slash and Raw String
5. path = '(I wrote the whole path form C:\Users and so on)...\Photos\dog1.jpg' Whole path and Backwards Slash
6. path = '(I wrote the whole path form C:\Users and so on)...\Photos\dog1.jpg' Whole Path and Double Backwards Slash
7. path = '(I wrote the whole path form C:\Users and so on).../Photos/dog1.jpg' Whole Path and Normal Slash
8. path = r'(I wrote the whole path form C:\Users and so on)...\Photos\dog1.jpg' Whole Path, Raw String and Backwards Slash

Comment: I think I saw this error before - usually problem is that `imread()` doesn't raise error when file doesn't exist but it return empty data - and later `imshow()` can't display it and you get error. You should check if your file really exists. Maybe first try `/full/path/to/Photos/dog1.jpg`. And you can also check `os.path.exists("/full/path/to/Photos/dog1.jpg")` to check if it really exists - maybe you made some mistake in path. Maybe it is not `jpg` but `JPG` or `jpeg`, etc. maybe it should be lower `p` in `photo`, or maybe some folder has `space` in name and you forgot use it in path, etc.

Comment: you may also use `os.listdir()` to see what you have in current folder. If you run code from different folder (not from folder with code) then it may search `Photos` in different folder. You can check `os.getcwd()` to get `Current Working Directory`

Comment: and last thing: check if you can open this file in any `image viewer` - maybe file is broken.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you're just not using the correct path to the file.  As @furas commented, you can call `os.listdir()` on the directory where you think the file is, to see the **actual** contents of the folder.

Comment: @Aybar. Can you show full traceback error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\Opencv\read.py", line 19, in <module>
    cv.imshow('Dog', img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow' The full trace back error si this and I relaized it now it also give an warning like this [ WARN:0@0.055] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('C:\Users\...\Opencv\dogg.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to the way you are specifying the path to the image file. Additionally, there's a small mistake in the `cv.destroyAllWindows` line, it should be a function call `cv.destroyAllWindows()`.

Here's an example of how you can specify the path using a raw string and double backslashes:

```py
import cv2 as cv

# Use raw string and double backslashes
path = r'Photos\dog1.jpg'

# Read the image
img = cv.imread(path)

# Check if the image is successfully loaded
if img is not None:
    # Display the image
    cv.imshow('Dog', img)

    # Wait for a key press and close the window
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    print(f"Error: Unable to read the image at path: {path}")
```

Make sure that the image file 'dog1.jpg' is located in the 'Photos' directory relative to the location of your script. Also, check for any typos in the folder and file names.

If you are still facing issues, you might want to print the absolute path to verify that it is correctly formed. You can use the `os.path.abspath()` function for this purpose:

```py
import os

path = r'Photos\dog1.jpg'
absolute_path = os.path.abspath(path)
print(absolute_path)
```

This will print the absolute path to the console, and you can verify if it matches the actual location of your image file.

Comment: Fisrtly thank you for helping me. I tried all of them but It can't read the file the path is correct when I try to do the same thing with txt file in the same directory as the dog.jpeg  it can read it without any problmes but when it comes to showing and reading the photo it can't there is something wrong other than the path or path integrty.

Comment: Also It give the traceback error when I try to show the image (the eror I have talked about) when I try to read it it give a warning like this [ WARN:0@0.069] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('C:\Users\...\Opencv\dogg.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity